# Apache Spark EC2 Script launching slaves but no master

Tags: apache-spark, spark-ec2

When using the Apache Spark EC2 script to launch a cluster I have found somewhat of a bug which is beginning to hit my pocket. When specifying the number of slaves: if you enter a number which is greater than or equal to your limit then the cluster is launched with your maximum number of slaves - but no master! This gives you no control over the slaves and thus cluster.

I have not found a way to launch just a master with the Apache Spark EC2 script. I have manually shut down 1 of the slaves to make space for a master; however, when then trying to re-launch the script it just says:

```
Searching for existing cluster my_cluster...
Found 0 master(s), 4 slaves
ERROR: There are already instances running in group my_cluster-master
or my_cluster-slaves
```

To overcome this, I have to log into the AWS console and terminate all the clusters and then restart. As Amazon charge per hour I am being charged for a full hours worth of my maximum number of clusters - all for nothing.

Is there a way to launch a master when slaves already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because spark-ec2 makes 2 separate requests to EC2 to allocate instances, one for the master and one for the slaves.

And as you might guess, it [allocates the master instance *after* the slaves](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/50ab8a6543ad5c31e89c16df374d0cb13222fd1e/ec2/spark_ec2.py#L633-L655), which is causing the issue you are seeing.

There is no way to launch a master when slaves already exist. Only the reverse is supported--launching slaves when a master already exists.

This behavior of launching the master after the slaves sounds like a bug.

If you'd like to report it so it gets fixed, I suggest creating an issue on the [Apache JIRA](http://issues.apache.org/jira/) for Spark under the EC2 component. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll create an issue with them for sure!